# float value condition

Tags: c, floating-point, floating-point-conversion

I worked out the following code and got a bizarre output. Can anyone explain how it works?

```
main()
{
    float a=0.8;
    float b=0.25;
    if(a==0.8)
        printf("HELLO")
    if(b==0.25)
        printf("WORLD")
}
```

And the output that I got is surprisingly

```
WORLD
```

thanks in advance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is because 0.25 is a power of two (i.e. 2^-2), while 0.8 is not. Only exact sums of powers of two can be represented exactly; all other numbers, including 0.8, are represented as an approximation, which has a different precision between `float` and `double`. The `0.8` in `a==0.8` is a `double`, while `a` is a `float`. Their representations are different, and so are their values.

Comment: you are the fastest gun in SO , dude. I was clicking "post your answer", and I AM really quick.

Comment: just add a printf("%1.12f", a);
to your code and you will see the rounding error

Answer (score 3):

You must never compare `float`-values against absolute values as you did. There are usually slight rounding errors, as a float is represented according IEEE 754 and the machine is not capable of providing exact float-values.

Have a look [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_floating_point) for your explanation and especially the rounding-rules.

Answer (score 2):

you are comparing float against double. Try putting an f after the number

```
if(a==0.8f)
    printf("HELLO")
if(b==0.25f)
    printf("WORLD")
```

Answer (score 0):

the given answers are right... on Dr Dobb's Andrew Koenig is writing about order relationship with floats, have a view:

[its-hard-to-compare-floating-point-numbers](http://www.drdobbs.com/cpp/its-hard-to-compare-floating-point-numbe/240149806)

[comparing-an-integer-with-a-floating-point1](http://www.drdobbs.com/cpp/comparing-an-integer-with-a-floating-poi/240150323)

Comment: I don't see the answer to the question at hand in these two articles. The answer is that `a` is `0.8f` and that `0.8f` is different from the double-precision constant `0.8`.

Answer (score 0):

Everything is stored eventually in bits.... So floating points get rounded off in case their binary equivalents are recurring...